# struct char* over tcp

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct pkt {    
    unsigned int        pktid;
    unsigned int        pkt_leng;
    unsigned int        strleng;
    char*           str;
};
```

in my code I'm doing this:

```
mystring = someFunctionWhoReturnString();

pkt* mypkt = (pkt*) malloc(sizeof(pkt));

mypkt -> pkt                    = htonl(C_MYPKT);
mypkt -> pkt_leng               = htonl(sizeof(pkt));
mpykt -> strleng                = htonl(mystring.lengh());

mypkt -> str = (char*)malloc(mystring.length());
strcpy(mypkt -> str, mystring.c_str(), mystring.length());
```

after this, if i check what is stored on mypkt->str, the string its there.

but when i receive the pkt, i got just some garbage (the size is fine) where suppose to get the char* (the rest of the data in the packet arrive ok).

There is some smart way to accomplish this task without use a char[] with static size?

Im working on VC++ 2010.

Comment: You can't send pointers across a network and expect them to be valid at the receiving end.  You'll need to send the actual string.  char[], not char*.  Fwiw, you can't reliably send a struct or int either.  Structure packing, endian-ness and the number of bits in an int get certainly get you into trouble as well.  Reasons why xml and protobuf are popular.

Comment: thanks you, pretty clear.

Comment: Don't use structs as network protocols. Define a wire protocol in terms of octets, and then write the code to send and receive it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realize that `sizeof(pkt) == 12`, the size of three integers and a pointer. It doesn't include the length of the data the pointer points to. What you are sending over is three integers and the address of the string on the sending machine - an address that's completely useless to the receiving machine, of course.

Instead, you need to prepare a flat buffer that would have three integers immediately followed by character data.